# Django Nose - Need to capture output while running tests

Tags: python, django, django-nose

I am running running django-nose tests in a management command using `call_command`. I need to capture output and do something with it, depending on if it failed or passed.
My current code in management command :

```
content = StringIO()
try:
    call_command('test', '--nologcapture', '-s', stdout=content)
        # since its calling system exit
except BaseException:
    pass
content.seek(0)
print content.read(), '<-- content'

# Check if test is passed and do something or else something else.
```

In my case, the content is always an empty string.

I tried a lot of nose plugins, but cannot fetch output.

Thanks.